# Migrating Portal to completely different host

Tags: portal, dotnetnuke

Pretty new to DNN so please be kind...
I am assisting a friend who hosts websites for many non-profit organizations.  He is trying to migrate all of them to DNN to allow them to maintain the sites themselves.  One was set up successfully last year as PortalID = 0 and uses the default database.

Then a friend requested hosting on DNN and we set them up as another portal as PortalID = 1.  Now this friend is moving hosts and we are somewhat in a quandary.  It looks like all portal data is being stored in the same default database.

Our question is how do we moved the portal data into individual databases so it will be quite easy to backup the database and send it to the client?  And where do we set up the databases when we create a new portal?   Or did we set this up incorrectly?

Please be somewhat specific if you answer.  I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of handling this is to set up each customer with a separate DotNetNuke install (the multi-portal feature should only be used from intra-organizational content).

In order to do what you are wanting, you should do a clone-and-purge method for your customer.  Keep in mind that there may be artifacts left over in the database, but it would be the best thing for you and your customer.  If you need help doing that, I would recommend touching base with http://www.DNNHelp.com.

(I work for http://www.PowerDNN.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend copying the site and database, and then deleting the other portal(s) (I suppose this is what Tony refers to as a "clone-and-purge").  I'm assuming that you'll be able to backup the site and restore it somewhere else (make sure to setup a portal alias where you can access the new site).  Then, from the Host -> Sites page (where you would create a new portal), you can delete the other portal(s) that you don't want in the database.  Once that's done, you can delete the portal from the original site, and have two separate, unconnected sites.

Portals for the same instance will always share the same database, so if you want separate databases, you should be creating new DNN instances, not new portals.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the above long methods there is a short cut to do this. Here is how easily you can do it:

- Login to host and export the template from the portal you want to migrate
- Create packages for all the custom skins, container and modules you used.
- Send all these files to your customer
- your customer has to install the skins, containers and modules to their website (OR he can just drop it to respective folders for skin, container and module in install directory at root of dnn instance and run installresource)
- Once you are done with above step, you can simply go to create portal and create a new portal by using a template.
- Please remember to check include content while exporting your portal template in order to get data for all the modules like text/html (and other modules which implementes iexportalble)

I hope this will help.